# How can we remove closed button from closed case?

Tags: visualforce

I want to know that is it possible to remove the close button from a closed case  and only add reopen button only on closed case is it possible to do so ... If yes then how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create two different record types and have a different page layout assigned to each record type .In one page layout remove the Close case button .As soon as the Case is closed you will need a workflow to change the recordtype of the Closed Case and that would change layout automatically .

Answer (score 1):

I would agree with Mohith if you are using standard page layouts.  Since you included the Visualforce tag on your question, I would offer a different answer.   For an object overridden with a VF page, you  can conditionally render different buttons.  When then case is open, render a Close Case button that calls the close case action you want, and when the case is closed, call your custom reopen action.